# Not able to import the image_picker package | flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, imagepicker

I am not able to use the image_picker package, VS marks it as an error "Target of the URI doesn't exist"

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop project and do this `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get` and start it again.